# Extract time in getSymbols

Tags: r, quantmod

I want to extract the time for some stock market to fit tree model. For example these codes are for loading Nikkei Market data:

```
library(quantmod)
library(zoo)
symbols=c('^N225')
getSymbols(symbols,src='yahoo', from="2003-04-28", to="2007-10-29")
```

After that, I want to extract the time that the market is work (we could see the time in the first left column of the market data after we write `N225`). when we save these data with csv format the time column is replaced with ID number.
Someone say that use the zoo format and after I save the data with these code:

```
N<-data.frame(N225)
Ndata<-read.zoo(N)
```

the warning has appeared as follow:

```
In zoo(rval, index(x)[i]) :
some methods for “zoo” objects do not work if the index entries in ‘order.by’ are not unique
```

and when we write `Ndata` the time column is replaced with some number that is not the time. how can I extract the time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't get your code to run, but this will get the same info. from the St. Louis Fed:

```
library(quantmod)
library(zoo)
symbols=c('NIKKEI225')
getSymbols(symbols,src='FRED')

df <- as.data.frame(NIKKEI225)
df <- cbind(date=as.Date(rownames(df)),df)
write.csv(df,file="Ndata.csv, row.names=F)
```

The problem is that `getSymbols(...)` returns a timeseries object, where the times are implicit. So when you save you just get the "time index", rather than a data-time variable. The code above makes the times explicit by putting them in a column of the dataframe, and explicitly setting them to class Date.

As @GSee points out in the comment below, this is another, better way:

```
df <- data.frame(date=index(NIKKEI225),NIKKEI225)
write.csv(df,file="Ndata.csv, row.names=F)
```

Comment: You can get the "times" -- which are stored as an index attribute -- with `index(NIKKEI225)` (or `index(N225)` using the OP's code).

Comment: @jlhoward, I don't Know that why  my code is not working for you(src="yahoo"), but it's work for me and thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `getSymbols` might be giving you trouble. I don't have a API key for Yahoo so I had to manually download the file and I did not have any trouble.

```
library(quantmod)
symbols=c('^N225')
getSymbols(symbols,src='yahoo', from="2003-04-28", to="2007-10-29")
#this returned an error so I had to manually read in the CSV file
N225 <- read.csv("table.csv")
Ndata <- read.zoo(N225)
head(Ndata)
           Open High  Low Close Volume Adj.Close
2003-04-28 7679 7685 7604  7608  46000      7608
2003-04-30 7695 7831 7695  7831  63200      7831
2003-05-01 7804 7896 7746  7863  55800      7863
2003-05-02 7863 7907 7792  7907  53400      7907
2003-05-06 7995 8133 7995  8084  61400      8084
2003-05-07 8127 8156 8062  8110  57600      8110
```

Comment: After loading data with getSymbols, when you type N225, it has the same output that you share, but I want to gain the time not show that in Rconsole. For example I want to gain the first column that start with 2003-04-28. When you save the the data it has not any of these time in csv file.

Comment: What do you mean by save the data? Are you writing to a text file? If so, try `write.zoo(Ndata, file = "Ndata.csv", index.name = "Index", row.names = TRUE)`